# Undefined References in CBLAS when testing GSL with CMake

Tags: c, blas, gsl, cblas

I've just installed GSL on my Deepin OS(Linux), and for testing my installation I'm trying to compile a testing file. When compiling with `gcc`, it works properly, but when using CMake, some `Undefined Reference` error occurs.

I tried compiling the file `main.c` with `gcc` :

```sh
gcc main.c -o demo -lm -lgsl -lgslcblas
./demo
```

and it works properly. But when I tried CMake :

```sh
cmake .
make
```

with a CMakeLists.txt file that looks like :

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(demo)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.c)
add_executable(demo ${SOURCE_FILES})

find_package(GSL REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(demo GSL::gsl GSL::gslcblas)
```

such error occurs ：

**(The output is in Chinese, because of the system language. For example :**

```sh
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_srotg.o)：在函数‘cblas_srotg’中：
cblas_srotg.c:(.text+0x1)：对‘srotg_’未定义的引用
```

**means :**

```sh
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_srotg.o)：In function ‘cblas_srotg’ ：
cblas_srotg.c:(.text+0x1)：Undefined reference to ‘srotg_’.
```

**)**

```sh
[ 50%] Linking C executable demo
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_srotg.o)：在函数‘cblas_srotg’中：
cblas_srotg.c:(.text+0x1)：对‘srotg_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_srotmg.o)：在函数‘cblas_srotmg’中：
cblas_srotmg.c:(.text+0x13)：对‘srotmg_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_srot.o)：在函数‘cblas_srot’中：
cblas_srot.c:(.text+0x3c)：对‘srot_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_srotm.o)：在函数‘cblas_srotm’中：
cblas_srotm.c:(.text+0x21)：对‘srotm_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_sswap.o)：在函数‘cblas_sswap’中：
cblas_sswap.c:(.text+0x21)：对‘sswap_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_sscal.o)：在函数‘cblas_sscal’中：
cblas_sscal.c:(.text+0x28)：对‘sscal_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_scopy.o)：在函数‘cblas_scopy’中：
cblas_scopy.c:(.text+0x21)：对‘scopy_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_saxpy.o)：在函数‘cblas_saxpy’中：
cblas_saxpy.c:(.text+0x35)：对‘saxpy_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(sdotsub.o)：在函数‘sdotsub_’中：
sdotsub.f:(.text+0x7)：对‘sdot_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(sdsdotsub.o)：在函数‘sdsdotsub_’中：
sdsdotsub.f:(.text+0x7)：对‘sdsdot_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(snrm2sub.o)：在函数‘snrm2sub_’中：
snrm2sub.f:(.text+0x7)：对‘snrm2_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(sasumsub.o)：在函数‘sasumsub_’中：
sasumsub.f:(.text+0x7)：对‘sasum_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(isamaxsub.o)：在函数‘isamaxsub_’中：
isamaxsub.f:(.text+0x7)：对‘isamax_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_drotg.o)：在函数‘cblas_drotg’中：
cblas_drotg.c:(.text+0x1)：对‘drotg_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_drotmg.o)：在函数‘cblas_drotmg’中：
cblas_drotmg.c:(.text+0x13)：对‘drotmg_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_drot.o)：在函数‘cblas_drot’中：
cblas_drot.c:(.text+0x3b)：对‘drot_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_drotm.o)：在函数‘cblas_drotm’中：
cblas_drotm.c:(.text+0x21)：对‘drotm_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_dswap.o)：在函数‘cblas_dswap’中：
cblas_dswap.c:(.text+0x21)：对‘dswap_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_dscal.o)：在函数‘cblas_dscal’中：
cblas_dscal.c:(.text+0x25)：对‘dscal_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_dcopy.o)：在函数‘cblas_dcopy’中：
cblas_dcopy.c:(.text+0x21)：对‘dcopy_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_daxpy.o)：在函数‘cblas_daxpy’中：
cblas_daxpy.c:(.text+0x38)：对‘daxpy_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(ddotsub.o)：在函数‘ddotsub_’中：
ddotsub.f:(.text+0x7)：对‘ddot_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(dsdotsub.o)：在函数‘dsdotsub_’中：
dsdotsub.f:(.text+0x7)：对‘dsdot_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(dnrm2sub.o)：在函数‘dnrm2sub_’中：
dnrm2sub.f:(.text+0x7)：对‘dnrm2_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(dasumsub.o)：在函数‘dasumsub_’中：
dasumsub.f:(.text+0x7)：对‘dasum_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(idamaxsub.o)：在函数‘idamaxsub_’中：
idamaxsub.f:(.text+0x7)：对‘idamax_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_cswap.o)：在函数‘cblas_cswap’中：
cblas_cswap.c:(.text+0x21)：对‘cswap_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_cscal.o)：在函数‘cblas_cscal’中：
cblas_cscal.c:(.text+0x17)：对‘cscal_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_csscal.o)：在函数‘cblas_csscal’中：
cblas_csscal.c:(.text+0x28)：对‘csscal_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_ccopy.o)：在函数‘cblas_ccopy’中：
cblas_ccopy.c:(.text+0x21)：对‘ccopy_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_caxpy.o)：在函数‘cblas_caxpy’中：
cblas_caxpy.c:(.text+0x21)：对‘caxpy_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cdotcsub.o)：在函数‘cdotcsub_’中：
cdotcsub.f:(.text+0xb)：对‘cdotc_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cdotusub.o)：在函数‘cdotusub_’中：
cdotusub.f:(.text+0xb)：对‘cdotu_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(icamaxsub.o)：在函数‘icamaxsub_’中：
icamaxsub.f:(.text+0x7)：对‘icamax_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_zswap.o)：在函数‘cblas_zswap’中：
cblas_zswap.c:(.text+0x21)：对‘zswap_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_zscal.o)：在函数‘cblas_zscal’中：
cblas_zscal.c:(.text+0x17)：对‘zscal_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_zdscal.o)：在函数‘cblas_zdscal’中：
cblas_zdscal.c:(.text+0x25)：对‘zdscal_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_zcopy.o)：在函数‘cblas_zcopy’中：
cblas_zcopy.c:(.text+0x21)：对‘zcopy_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_zaxpy.o)：在函数‘cblas_zaxpy’中：
cblas_zaxpy.c:(.text+0x21)：对‘zaxpy_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(zdotcsub.o)：在函数‘zdotcsub_’中：
zdotcsub.f:(.text+0x7)：对‘zdotc_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(zdotusub.o)：在函数‘zdotusub_’中：
zdotusub.f:(.text+0x7)：对‘zdotu_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(dzasumsub.o)：在函数‘dzasumsub_’中：
dzasumsub.f:(.text+0x7)：对‘dzasum_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(dznrm2sub.o)：在函数‘dznrm2sub_’中：
dznrm2sub.f:(.text+0x7)：对‘dznrm2_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(izamaxsub.o)：在函数‘izamaxsub_’中：
izamaxsub.f:(.text+0x7)：对‘izamax_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(scasumsub.o)：在函数‘scasumsub_’中：
scasumsub.f:(.text+0x7)：对‘scasum_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(scnrm2sub.o)：在函数‘scnrm2sub_’中：
scnrm2sub.f:(.text+0x7)：对‘scnrm2_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_sgemv.o)：在函数‘cblas_sgemv’中：
cblas_sgemv.c:(.text+0x124)：对‘sgemv_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_sger.o)：在函数‘cblas_sger’中：
cblas_sger.c:(.text+0xab)：对‘sger_’未定义的引用
cblas_sger.c:(.text+0xe3)：对‘sger_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_ssymv.o)：在函数‘cblas_ssymv’中：
cblas_ssymv.c:(.text+0xb4)：对‘ssymv_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_ssyr.o)：在函数‘cblas_ssyr’中：
cblas_ssyr.c:(.text+0xa8)：对‘ssyr_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_ssyr2.o)：在函数‘cblas_ssyr2’中：
cblas_ssyr2.c:(.text+0xb2)：对‘ssyr2_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_strmv.o)：在函数‘cblas_strmv’中：
cblas_strmv.c:(.text+0x141)：对‘strmv_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_strsv.o)：在函数‘cblas_strsv’中：
cblas_strsv.c:(.text+0x141)：对‘strsv_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_dgemv.o)：在函数‘cblas_dgemv’中：
cblas_dgemv.c:(.text+0x120)：对‘dgemv_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_dger.o)：在函数‘cblas_dger’中：
cblas_dger.c:(.text+0xb3)：对‘dger_’未定义的引用
cblas_dger.c:(.text+0xeb)：对‘dger_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_dsymv.o)：在函数‘cblas_dsymv’中：
cblas_dsymv.c:(.text+0xb4)：对‘dsymv_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_dsyr.o)：在函数‘cblas_dsyr’中：
cblas_dsyr.c:(.text+0xa6)：对‘dsyr_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_dsyr2.o)：在函数‘cblas_dsyr2’中：
cblas_dsyr2.c:(.text+0xb0)：对‘dsyr2_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_dtrmv.o)：在函数‘cblas_dtrmv’中：
cblas_dtrmv.c:(.text+0x141)：对‘dtrmv_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_dtrsv.o)：在函数‘cblas_dtrsv’中：
cblas_dtrsv.c:(.text+0x141)：对‘dtrsv_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_cgemv.o)：在函数‘cblas_cgemv’中：
cblas_cgemv.c:(.text+0x205)：对‘cgemv_’未定义的引用
cblas_cgemv.c:(.text+0x290)：对‘cgemv_’未定义的引用
cblas_cgemv.c:(.text+0x36d)：对‘cgemv_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_chemv.o)：在函数‘cblas_chemv’中：
cblas_chemv.c:(.text+0x219)：对‘chemv_’未定义的引用
cblas_chemv.c:(.text+0x2f0)：对‘chemv_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_ctrmv.o)：在函数‘cblas_ctrmv’中：
cblas_ctrmv.c:(.text+0x146)：对‘ctrmv_’未定义的引用
cblas_ctrmv.c:(.text+0x200)：对‘ctrmv_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_ctrsv.o)：在函数‘cblas_ctrsv’中：
cblas_ctrsv.c:(.text+0x154)：对‘ctrsv_’未定义的引用
cblas_ctrsv.c:(.text+0x210)：对‘ctrsv_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_cgeru.o)：在函数‘cblas_cgeru’中：
cblas_cgeru.c:(.text+0xa6)：对‘cgeru_’未定义的引用
cblas_cgeru.c:(.text+0xd9)：对‘cgeru_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_cgerc.o)：在函数‘cblas_cgerc’中：
cblas_cgerc.c:(.text+0x13d)：对‘cgeru_’未定义的引用
cblas_cgerc.c:(.text+0x18f)：对‘cgeru_’未定义的引用
cblas_cgerc.c:(.text+0x1ef)：对‘cgerc_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_cher.o)：在函数‘cblas_cher’中：
cblas_cher.c:(.text+0x10a)：对‘cher_’未定义的引用
cblas_cher.c:(.text+0x1f7)：对‘cher_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_cher2.o)：在函数‘cblas_cher2’中：
cblas_cher2.c:(.text+0x17a)：对‘cher2_’未定义的引用
cblas_cher2.c:(.text+0x281)：对‘cher2_’未定义的引用
cblas_cher2.c:(.text+0x2bc)：对‘cher2_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_zgemv.o)：在函数‘cblas_zgemv’中：
cblas_zgemv.c:(.text+0x20f)：对‘zgemv_’未定义的引用
cblas_zgemv.c:(.text+0x298)：对‘zgemv_’未定义的引用
cblas_zgemv.c:(.text+0x37c)：对‘zgemv_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_zhemv.o)：在函数‘cblas_zhemv’中：
cblas_zhemv.c:(.text+0x219)：对‘zhemv_’未定义的引用
cblas_zhemv.c:(.text+0x2f0)：对‘zhemv_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_ztrmv.o)：在函数‘cblas_ztrmv’中：
cblas_ztrmv.c:(.text+0x155)：对‘ztrmv_’未定义的引用
cblas_ztrmv.c:(.text+0x210)：对‘ztrmv_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_ztrsv.o)：在函数‘cblas_ztrsv’中：
cblas_ztrsv.c:(.text+0x155)：对‘ztrsv_’未定义的引用
cblas_ztrsv.c:(.text+0x210)：对‘ztrsv_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_zgeru.o)：在函数‘cblas_zgeru’中：
cblas_zgeru.c:(.text+0xa6)：对‘zgeru_’未定义的引用
cblas_zgeru.c:(.text+0xd9)：对‘zgeru_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_zgerc.o)：在函数‘cblas_zgerc’中：
cblas_zgerc.c:(.text+0x13e)：对‘zgeru_’未定义的引用
cblas_zgerc.c:(.text+0x18f)：对‘zgeru_’未定义的引用
cblas_zgerc.c:(.text+0x1ef)：对‘zgerc_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_zher.o)：在函数‘cblas_zher’中：
cblas_zher.c:(.text+0x14b)：对‘zher_’未定义的引用
cblas_zher.c:(.text+0x1a5)：对‘zher_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_zher2.o)：在函数‘cblas_zher2’中：
cblas_zher2.c:(.text+0x17b)：对‘zher2_’未定义的引用
cblas_zher2.c:(.text+0x281)：对‘zher2_’未定义的引用
cblas_zher2.c:(.text+0x2bc)：对‘zher2_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_sgemm.o)：在函数‘cblas_sgemm’中：
cblas_sgemm.c:(.text+0x10f)：对‘sgemm_’未定义的引用
cblas_sgemm.c:(.text+0x1a7)：对‘sgemm_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_ssymm.o)：在函数‘cblas_ssymm’中：
cblas_ssymm.c:(.text+0xe8)：对‘ssymm_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_ssyrk.o)：在函数‘cblas_ssyrk’中：
cblas_ssyrk.c:(.text+0xd7)：对‘ssyrk_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_ssyr2k.o)：在函数‘cblas_ssyr2k’中：
cblas_ssyr2k.c:(.text+0xe5)：对‘ssyr2k_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_strmm.o)：在函数‘cblas_strmm’中：
cblas_strmm.c:(.text+0x12a)：对‘strmm_’未定义的引用
cblas_strmm.c:(.text+0x1f0)：对‘strmm_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_strsm.o)：在函数‘cblas_strsm’中：
cblas_strsm.c:(.text+0x12a)：对‘strsm_’未定义的引用
cblas_strsm.c:(.text+0x1f0)：对‘strsm_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_dgemm.o)：在函数‘cblas_dgemm’中：
cblas_dgemm.c:(.text+0x10f)：对‘dgemm_’未定义的引用
cblas_dgemm.c:(.text+0x1a7)：对‘dgemm_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_dsymm.o)：在函数‘cblas_dsymm’中：
cblas_dsymm.c:(.text+0xe8)：对‘dsymm_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_dsyrk.o)：在函数‘cblas_dsyrk’中：
cblas_dsyrk.c:(.text+0xd7)：对‘dsyrk_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_dsyr2k.o)：在函数‘cblas_dsyr2k’中：
cblas_dsyr2k.c:(.text+0xe5)：对‘dsyr2k_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_dtrmm.o)：在函数‘cblas_dtrmm’中：
cblas_dtrmm.c:(.text+0x122)：对‘dtrmm_’未定义的引用
cblas_dtrmm.c:(.text+0x1e0)：对‘dtrmm_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_dtrsm.o)：在函数‘cblas_dtrsm’中：
cblas_dtrsm.c:(.text+0x122)：对‘dtrsm_’未定义的引用
cblas_dtrsm.c:(.text+0x1e0)：对‘dtrsm_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_cgemm.o)：在函数‘cblas_cgemm’中：
cblas_cgemm.c:(.text+0x105)：对‘cgemm_’未定义的引用
cblas_cgemm.c:(.text+0x19d)：对‘cgemm_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_csymm.o)：在函数‘cblas_csymm’中：
cblas_csymm.c:(.text+0xe6)：对‘csymm_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_chemm.o)：在函数‘cblas_chemm’中：
cblas_chemm.c:(.text+0xe6)：对‘chemm_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_cherk.o)：在函数‘cblas_cherk’中：
cblas_cherk.c:(.text+0xd7)：对‘cherk_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_cher2k.o)：在函数‘cblas_cher2k’中：
cblas_cher2k.c:(.text+0x108)：对‘cher2k_’未定义的引用
cblas_cher2k.c:(.text+0x185)：对‘cher2k_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_ctrmm.o)：在函数‘cblas_ctrmm’中：
cblas_ctrmm.c:(.text+0x118)：对‘ctrmm_’未定义的引用
cblas_ctrmm.c:(.text+0x1d6)：对‘ctrmm_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_ctrsm.o)：在函数‘cblas_ctrsm’中：
cblas_ctrsm.c:(.text+0x118)：对‘ctrsm_’未定义的引用
cblas_ctrsm.c:(.text+0x1d6)：对‘ctrsm_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_csyrk.o)：在函数‘cblas_csyrk’中：
cblas_csyrk.c:(.text+0xd5)：对‘csyrk_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_csyr2k.o)：在函数‘cblas_csyr2k’中：
cblas_csyr2k.c:(.text+0xe3)：对‘csyr2k_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_zgemm.o)：在函数‘cblas_zgemm’中：
cblas_zgemm.c:(.text+0x105)：对‘zgemm_’未定义的引用
cblas_zgemm.c:(.text+0x19d)：对‘zgemm_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_zsymm.o)：在函数‘cblas_zsymm’中：
cblas_zsymm.c:(.text+0xe6)：对‘zsymm_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_zhemm.o)：在函数‘cblas_zhemm’中：
cblas_zhemm.c:(.text+0xe6)：对‘zhemm_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_zherk.o)：在函数‘cblas_zherk’中：
cblas_zherk.c:(.text+0xd7)：对‘zherk_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_zher2k.o)：在函数‘cblas_zher2k’中：
cblas_zher2k.c:(.text+0x109)：对‘zher2k_’未定义的引用
cblas_zher2k.c:(.text+0x18d)：对‘zher2k_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_ztrmm.o)：在函数‘cblas_ztrmm’中：
cblas_ztrmm.c:(.text+0x118)：对‘ztrmm_’未定义的引用
cblas_ztrmm.c:(.text+0x1d6)：对‘ztrmm_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_ztrsm.o)：在函数‘cblas_ztrsm’中：
cblas_ztrsm.c:(.text+0x118)：对‘ztrsm_’未定义的引用
cblas_ztrsm.c:(.text+0x1d6)：对‘ztrsm_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_zsyrk.o)：在函数‘cblas_zsyrk’中：
cblas_zsyrk.c:(.text+0xd5)：对‘zsyrk_’未定义的引用
/usr/local/lib/libcblas.a(cblas_zsyr2k.o)：在函数‘cblas_zsyr2k’中：
cblas_zsyr2k.c:(.text+0xe3)：对‘zsyr2k_’未定义的引用
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/demo.dir/build.make:96: recipe for target 'demo' failed
make[2]: *** [demo] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/demo.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/demo.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed 
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

To determine how is the problem brought up, I also tried reproducing the error message with `gcc`. When compiling with this command :

```sh
$ gcc main.c -o demo -lm -lgsl -lcblas -lblas
```

it works well. When trying :

```sh
$ gcc main.c -o demo -lm -lgsl -lcblas # Ignoring BLAS library.
```

The error message is reproduced. So I guess the problem occurs when linking the BLAS library.

Here is the file `main.c`

```c
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h>
int main(void) {
  double x = 5.0;
  double y;
  y = gsl_sf_bessel_J0(x);
  printf("J0(%.4lf) = %.4le\n", x, y);
  return 0;
}
```

The expected outcome would be :

```
J0(5.0000) = -1.7760e-01
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your CMakeList.txt

```
find_package(BLAS REQUIRED)
```